# No break Type option too big for cell indesign

Tags: tables, cell

I'm creating a book in indesign cs5. I'm using a table to do a 2 column layout. When I set the block of copy to no break to get rid of all the hyphens in the cell, the type disappears. I try dragging the cell bigger but the type never shows up. I think a setting somewhere must be check causing problems. I've seen this question asked on other sites, but the best answer was to re-install!!

Comment: I don't know what you're doing but you aren't locked into a table to get two column layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply do not want hyphens, uncheck "Hyphenate" on the **Paragraph Panel**.

The "No Break" option in the Character Panel menu means "place all (selected) text on one single line" - a la - don't break text into multiple lines